# How to work with retrieved Core Data Objects

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

When I use DataCore to store data there are couple of limitations that makes me convert a lot of retrieved objects to regular class objects so I could work regularly with the data. The problem is that this kind of behavior creates some mediocre lines of code.

The limitations I face are:

A.Lack of ability to create an object with a constructor, using Init()

B.Limitation on property, specifically using didSet{} when a property changes.

For example you can't use didSet or create a constructor in this class :

```
   extension Time {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Time> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Time>(entityName: "Time")
    }

    @NSManaged public var hours: Int
    @NSManaged public var minutes: Int
    
}
```

How should I overcome this two limitations ?

2.Also, until now I created a DataCore entity object using this kind of code:

```
let timeEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Time", in: managedContext)!
    

let time = NSManagedObject(entity: timeEntity, insertInto: managedContext)
   time.setValue(10, forKeyPath: "hours")
   time.setValue(20, forKeyPath: "minutes")
```

Is that the appropriate way to create entity in Core Data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your second question first, no.  `Time` is a subclass of `NSManagedObject`.  You can use

```
let time = Time(context:managedContext)
```

Then you can access the properties of your `time` instance:

```
time.hours = 10
time.minutes = 20
```

To answer your second question, I would question if this is necessary; perhaps you could explain what you are trying to do.

You may be able to achieve the same thing you are looking for with a computed property that wraps `hour` and `minute`.

Comment: Thanks. I did set the code gen to manual, and this the code it created that I can edit, maybe this is not the "manual" way after all ?. How would you use didSet with those properties ? I tried and got "@NSManaged not allowed on observing properties".When using computed properties I am getting similar results: "@NSManaged not allowed on computed properties". I would appreciate a code example based on those properties in a way that I can use didSet or computed properties.

Comment: You can't make a computed property `@NSManaged` but you could use a computed property to get/set the actual properties. Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I have a property of "var dateComponents : DateComponents" which can't be NSManaged as far as I know. This property needs to be initialized when creating the class object. With regular class I used a constructor to initialize the dateComponents property and updated the dateComponents property using didSet whenever any other property changed.

Comment: Ok. Sounds like you can simply add that property as a computed property via an extension.